# Spring, Hibernate EhCache with monitoring service

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache, jconsole, ehcache-3

I am using Spring 4.3.7, Hibernate 5.2.9, hibernate-jcache 5.2.10 and ehcache 3.3.1.

this is relevant JPA configuration properties:

```
 properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.put("hibernate.javax.cache.provider", "org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
        properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
```

I have configured L2 caching on my entities and queries.

In console log output  I can see some caching is taking place. But I want to use `jconsole` to explore the statistics.

My question is how do I expose JMX statistics service of these package versions for `jconsole` to be able to render the stats?

All I have is:

```
@Bean
    public void ehCacheManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Vedantas.PU_NAME);
        SessionFactory sf = emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

        StatisticsService statsMBean = new StatisticsService();
        statsMBean.setSessionFactory(sf);
        statsMBean.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        mBeanServer.registerMBean(statsMBean, new ObjectName("Hibernate:application=Statistics"));
    }
```

which is the `Enable JMX support inside Hibernate - Using the API` section from the [jconsole documentation](http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/usage.html#pre-requisites)  which doesn't really help because 
`StatisticsService` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

So, please provide me some working configuration.
Also, running `java -jar hibernate-jconsole-1.0.7.jar` does nothing in my environment. why is that so?
Thanks!

Comment: You want Hibernate statistics right? Not cache statistics?

Comment: well, I want both. but have to admit I have migrated to Hazelcast which have a nice monitoring app cause this was very poorly documented and messed up with version change to 3.x so I may not be able to follow, but if you have something working you can post it for future reference i guess

Comment: On the cache side, when using JSR107, statistics are directly available in JMX. If you don't need clustered replication, Hazelcast is a bit overkill